# Adding a functional component to useeffect method in react js

Tags: reactjs, mdbreact

I'm trying to adding a sample `ModalPage` functional component in the useEffect method, but it is showing an error:

[image]

```
const [data, setData] = React.useState('');

useEffect(() => {
  const requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
   };
fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/users/getUserDetails', requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(res => {
    const data = {
      columns: [{
          label: 'First Name',
          field: 'FirstName',
          sort: 'asc',
          width: 150
        },
        {
          label: 'Last Name',
          field: 'LastName',
          sort: 'asc',
          width: 270
        },
        {
          label: 'Email',
          field: 'Email',
          sort: 'asc',
          width: 200
        },
        {
          label: 'Phone Number',
          field: 'PhoneNumber',
          sort: 'asc',
          width: 100
        },
        {
          label: 'Edit',
          field: 'Edit',
          width: 100
        },
       ],
      rows: res.isUser.map((data) => ({
        FirstName: data.firstName,
        LastName: data.LastName,
        Email: data.email,
        PhoneNumber: data.phoneNumber,
        edit :  <ModalPage/>
      }))
    }
    setData(data);
  })
}, [])
```

this is the modal page

```
  export default function ModalPage() {
   const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false);

    function toggle () {
      setShow({
       show: !show
      });
    }

  return (
     <MDBContainer>
      <MDBBtn onClick={toggle}>Modal</MDBBtn>
       <MDBModal isOpen={show} toggle={toggle}>
       <MDBModalHeader toggle={toggle}>MDBModal title</MDBModalHeader>
        <MDBModalBody>
        (...)
        </MDBModalBody>
       <MDBModalFooter>
      <MDBBtn color="secondary" onClick={toggle}>Close</MDBBtn>
      <MDBBtn color="primary">Save changes</MDBBtn>
    </MDBModalFooter>
  </MDBModal>
</MDBContainer>
);
}
```

Comment: The problem is not related to `useEffect` the problem is related to `useState` because you can not use <ModalPage /> in `useEffect`

Comment: is there any other way to call the `modal component`

Comment: Yes, you can concat that rows in render function and it will work

Answer (score 0):

As @Nisharg Shah said, you can't call `<ModalPage/>` inside of the `useEffect` hook. Try changing it to this:

```
  rows: res.isUser.map((data) => ({
    FirstName: data.firstName,
    LastName: data.LastName,
    Email: data.email,
    PhoneNumber: data.phoneNumber,
    Edit:  ModalPage // Note the removal of the tags "</>"
  }))
```

Then to render you can add this to your return statement:

```
    <MDBModalBody>
        {data.rows.map(row => <Edit/>)}
    </MDBModalBody>
```

Comment: how to define rows, Edit in modalPage component, because it is showing an error called `not defined`

Comment: I edited to make it clearer - it needs to be data.rows

Comment: need to define `data` and `Edit/>` in modal component , it is throwing an error

src\components\users\modalUser.js
  Line 19:14:  'data' is not defined  
  Line 19:36:  'Edit' is not defined